# Building artifacts for multiple java architectures using Maven (anything better than profiles)?

Tags: maven-2, maven

Having read about every posting and question that I can find, I'm stumped on finding a better way than just using profiles of doing the following.

I need to take the same set of modules, and compile them for vastly different architectures (J2ME vs. J2SE), they need different dependencies for some libraries, and they need different source/target/debug settings at compilation time.

Using profiles and classifiers, I can do this by running with one profile, cleaning, and running a build with the other profile.  The classifiers sort out the results.  However, if you just change profiles and rebuild, it won't clean on it's own, it requires multiple running of maven against the super-pom, and it won't allow you to enable multiple profiles at the same time (and the resultant mess when you do is pretty ugly).

Could I do something using attached artifacts and forcing the compile and jar steps to run multiple times?

The javac options are really the kicker: (using profiles for the dependencies doesn't cause any issues)

for J2ME:
source=1.4
target=1.4
-g:source

for J2ME debugging
source=1.4
target=1.4

for J2SE
source=1.5
target=1.5

Comment: I really want to help.  Can I get a little more information?  Are you needing multiple versions of each module?  Is there a "parent" artifact that you are trying to have multiple versions of, like a JAR file for J2ME/J2ME-debug/J2SE.

Comment: Yes, every jar (multi-module project) needs to be compiled with both settings.  I'm using a top-level pom to drive all the profiles and compiler settings, and it references all the individual jars as modules.  It also drives the dependencies, but that's mostly a runtime issue (I need different versions of a certain jar for J2ME vs. J2SE), and not nearly as problematic as the compilation issue is.

Comment: btw, I've tried executions as well, but both compilation executions are executed, and then both packaging executions are executed, so the resultant jars all have identical contents.

Comment: Can u share your pom.xml details, how you have handled this?

Comment: I think this kind of situation is exactly what profiles are for.

Comment: And I am using profiles, but it's still very, very clunky.  Mainly because I need to re-run for each target to get a complete set of jars together.

Comment: This sounds like "works as designed" - the design just isn't very apt for your use-case and/or your taste.  I'm not recommending this, but you _might_ want to consider a structure where you have separate projects for each environment, which share code from a common base via build-helper:add-source et al.  If you're using IDE integration (e.g. m2eclipse), I'd check that it works well before exploring this option any further.

Comment: Coming back to this much, much later:  I was able to make profiles work, but it had a lot of other issues (like the fact that the profiles weren't picked up in dependencies).  So in the end, I setup a multi-module project that included all the source I needed into a separate module by overriding the source locations in the pom.  That created a separate artifact that was for J2ME, and _that_ worked fantastically, especially as the project evolved and more was needed to be done to deal with the special case of J2ME vs. J2SE.

Answer (score 2):

Could you explicitly invoke the compiler plugin [Maven Compiler Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/) and then define multiple executions. Some thing like

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>compile1</id>
          <phase>generate-resources</phase>
          <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
                <fork>true</fork>
                <executable><!-- path-to-javac --></executable>
                <compilerVersion>1.3</compilerVersion>
            </configuration>
       </execution>
       <execution>
          <id>compile1</id>
          <phase>generate-resources</phase>
          <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
                <fork>true</fork>
                <executable><!-- path-to-javac --></executable>
                <compilerVersion>1.3</compilerVersion>
            </configuration>
       </execution>
   </executions>
  </plugin>
```